# Possible to refresh browser page from another tab

Tags: javascript, html, silverlight, firefox

I have a silverlight application. This contains a "preview" button. 
Button code is as follows:

```
private void btn_Preview(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"),"_blank");
}
```

When I clicking the button in firefox, a new page is created in a new tab. When I click again, another new page is created in another new tab. When i click 10 times, 10 tabs are created.

I want that If my target page already opened, don't create new tab. only refresh previous tab.

Same as google [blogger](http://www.blogger.com) `Preview` button of "edit html" section

I want do it from [silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net) 4 or javascript

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `_blank` to a unique name for your application.

```
private void btn_Preview(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"),"myApplicationName_previewWindow");
}
```

With `_blank` you are specifically asking it to open a new window each time.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving `_blank` as the name of the new window, give a particular name like `preview_window`. Then all the clicks should open the content in same window.

Note: I don't know Silverlight. I am guessing the solution from the similar behaviour in JavaScript.